# What does “to the numbers” mean in landing clearance?

Tags: traffic-pattern, clearance

Last night I was left downwind, abeam the tower, on my second circuit of the pattern. The controller said “helicopter xyz, cleared for the option runway 24, to the numbers”. I already had been given a restriction to stay east of rwy 18; as there was an airplane in right traffic there. What is the significance of “to the numbers” in this clearance? Is he just telling me not to land long?

Answer (score 15):

Typically it's phrased as "direct to the numbers" and means you should proceed in a straight line from your present position to where the runway numbers are painted on the pavement. This instruction can be issued to fixed-wing aircraft as well, but perhaps not from as wide a range of starting positions. It relieves you of any previous restrictions.

Comment: Ok, I see this described elsewhere as nonstandard phraseology for “make short approach”

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Pondlife, I must have been pretty tired when I wrote that

Comment: "Make short approach" means "don't go as far in the downwind as you normally would"—instead of turning base to set up for a two-mile final, set up for a one-mile final; instead of a normal one-mile final, make it a half-mile. "Direct the numbers" doesn't *literally* mean that your base leg should be in line with the approach end of the runway but it should be as close as you can get it. It's definitely more intense than "make short approach."